# Hidden files on USB drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have a lot of necessary files and documents on USB Drive. when i connect it to other PC it gets to as hidden and .EXE. Are there any way to make  them un hidden and cleaned?

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/645787/windows-command-line-unset-hidden-and-system-attributes-for-all-hidden-files, and http://superuser.com/questions/366561/windows-how-turn-off-hidden-attribute-for-all-files-and-directories-on-a-drive

Comment: Also... scan for malware.

Comment: That issue is solved and can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that you can see hidden files and folders. You can edit this in your folder settings.

Next, from "My Computer" double click on your USB drive, opening its root directory. Select all files (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. Now right click on the selected files and select "Properties". Uncheck the "Hidden" checkbox. Click op "Ok"

Comment: There is no such functions: Uncheck the "Hidden" checkbox. Click op "Ok"  thanks

Comment: Sorry. It works only from your root directory; not from your drive. I adapted the anser.